# How to disable code blocks in an Emacs org-mode init file

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel, tags

My dot emacs config consists of a short init.el file and a very large org file in which I have created dozens of emacs-lisp code-blocks. This works very well for me, especially in terms of organization. Every now I then I wish to temporarily disable one of these code blocks without having to delete the blocks in part or altogether. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? At present I tend to archive the code blacks to another file. However, I would like to keep them in the same file, and activate them if I need them. Is there a tag that might do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the state of a header to COMMENT:

```
** COMMENT This will not be tangled
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(foo)
#+END_SRC
```

`C-c ;` runs the command `org-toggle-comment`.

Comment: It seems to me it still tangles child headlings, though... Is this correct?

Comment: Not for me `Org mode version 9.4 (9.4-41-g9bb930-elpaplus @ /home/kdm/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20201116/)`

Comment: No it was something else that went wrong, it works as expected now. Sorry for the noise!